# Change HTML Document Title On Localhost but not Server

Tags: title

I am trying to change the title of a page based on the URL query params.
It works on localhost but not server.
I used the following hooks and all not working on server

`wp_title`

`‎document_title_parts‎`

`pre_get_document_title`

I used `print_r` to check the function work in its different steps and it works well on server, However, the document title doesn't change

---

An example using`document_title_parts`

```
function change_page_title($title)
{
    if ($GLOBALS["pagename"]) === "my-page") {
        $title['title'] = "new title";
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'change_page_title');
```

---

**Update**
When I change the theme to "Twenty Twenty Three" on the server it works, so I guess there is something in my current theme that prevents the hook job

Comment: What code are you actually using to change it?

Comment: I updated and added a code example

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would work locally but not on the server. Are you sure you're making the change in the right place on the server (or on the right server to begin with, I've made that mistake before)? How are you deploying the change to the server?

Comment: It is a plugin.
Can you further explain the "right place"?
Also what was your mistake

Comment: When I change the theme to "Twenty Twenty Three" on the server it works, so I guess there is something in my current theme that prevents the hook job

Comment: Does your theme support the title tag? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#title-tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148069/discussion-between-amir-latif-and-jacob-peattie).